# What to do when there are three return possibilities for a method?

Tags: c++, return-type

I was working on a project in C++ and found myself needing a method that determined what phase a substance was in (solid, liquid, or gas). There are only three possibilities here; I find myself in similar situations a lot, and while it seems obvious to just use integers (0, 1, 2 or 1, 2, 3), I've found that in practice this is unclear compared to Booleans. The other possibility I thought of was to make three methods, isLiquid, isGas, and isSolid, that each return a Boolean, but that seems inefficient. I was just wondering if anyone knows which one of these two possibilities is better, or if there's another idea I'm missing.

Comment: Discover `enum`.

Comment: Are you familiar with [enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)?

Comment: @n.m. won't that be just the first choice he's thinking about?

Comment: Pretty new to programming, I've heard of enums but don't know what they are. looking at them now

Comment: @AlphaMineron There is a huge difference between using an `enum` and "using an `int` and remembering what specific values mean, as well as remembering that you should try to stay within the range of defined values".

Comment: @Allball103 Tip: If you don't know something, look it up, it might help you in the future.

Comment: @Rakete1111 you're probably right but if i looked up every coding term I saw I'd never get to actually write programs.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh yea, I do get that. But i just pointed it out because he was thinking of using a sequence (0,1,2) like enum. I hope I'm not missing something big.

Comment: @AlphaMineron No, especially if using C++11 scoped enums which don't implicitly convert to integral types.

Comment: @Allball103 What could a simple way to do it? Imagine to return an integral value from the function where `1` means solid, `2` gas and `3` liquid. `enum` is an improved version of this approach.

Comment: @Allball103  If you *don't* look up things you don't know *you'll never get understand what you are doing*.  Asking on StackOverflow should all ways be your *last* resort, not your first instinct.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's a really simple solution. Just curious about downvotes: is there something fundamentally wrong with my question or is it just getting downvotes because it's dumb and has a simple solution? I'm not upset I'm just genuinely trying to improve my questions on here.

Comment: @snb dude if I'd known enums were a solution here I would've looked them up. I tried googling things similar to my question and came up short, I didn't realize there was an entire return type I was missing.

Comment: I think you could do with (re)reading a C++ text book.

Comment: @Allball103 I interpreted what you said earlier as "I didn't bother googling anything and opted to go on SO first".  If that is not the case then I'm sorry.  I am too also curious to why people are down-voting this question.

Comment: @EdHeal isn't this website about learning things that you don't know? I've never taken a C++ class, I'm trying to teach myself. Sorry if that's a crime

Comment: @Allball103 - I think reading a text book on C++ will help you a lot - just to get an understanding of the basics

Comment: @EdHeal except if you didn't go to school to learn c++, or didn't know of formal tutorials.  I could see some one even forgetting Enum exist.  This is not a bad question for people who don't know what they don't know

Comment: @EdHeal definitely on my to-do list. Taking a class next semester.

Comment: @snb - I did not downvote btw.

Comment: @Allball103 - Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list for a list of books

Comment: THat list looks amazing, thanks

Comment: @Allball103 _"you're probably right but if i looked up every coding term I saw I'd never get to actually write programs"_ Strange approach. How do you expect to learn? How do you think we learnt? lol. You should indeed perform basic research before asking for our time

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wish you'd read all the comments here: I DID do research before posting here. that quote was in reference to me saying that I'd heard the term enum before, but didn't know what it meant. Please do your research before wasting my time with your comment ;)

Comment: @Allball103: I did read them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an `enum` would probably simplify your code and make it more readable. I'll provide you with this example.

```
class Thing {
    enum MatterState {
        SOLID,
        LIQUID,
        GAS
    };

    MatterState state;

    // ... other variables

  public:

    // ... constructors, etc

    MatterState get_state() {
        return this->state;
    }
};
```

You specified *method*, so I provided you with a `class`.

Comment: Why the complication with using a class?

Comment: @EdHeal OP specified _method_, not function. EDIT: I figured someone would ask that, so I preemptively edited my post (at the bottom).

Comment: @Allball103 you're welcome. Mark as answer for future people.

Comment: I don't care enough to revert, but I had used the commented line numbers  to make it easier to refer to certain code phrases.